# SHA1 inconsistant between Play Game Services Log and Google Publishing?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, sha, prime31

I'm trying to get Google Play Game Services to work but I get the following error:

> 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/Prime31-GH: disconnect() called
> when client was already disconnected. 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/?
> W/GameHelper: **** 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: ****
> 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** APP NOT CORRECTLY
> CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES 06-15 15:53:20.599
> 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** This is usually caused by one of
> these reasons: 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** (1)
> Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match 06-15
> 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: ****     the client ID you
> registered in Developer Console. 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/?
> W/GameHelper: **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered. 06-15
> 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** (3) Your game settings
> have not been published and you are  06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/?
> W/GameHelper: ****     trying to log in with an account that is not
> listed as 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: ****     a
> test account. 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: ****
> 06-15 15:53:20.599 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** To help you debug,
> here is the information about this app 06-15 15:53:20.599
> 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** Package name         :
> net.jabberworx.saisai 06-15 15:53:20.607 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper:
> **** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: E5:E0:84:E6:B7:74:78:4F:6C:DA:E7:C9:56:69:81:10:6C:12:04:E8 06-15
> 15:53:20.607 17069-17069/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when
> getting value for resource number 0x00000000 06-15 15:53:20.607
> 17069-17069/? W/System.err:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>
> ## 0x0 06-15 15:53:20.607 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229) 06-15
>
> 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:313) 06-15
> 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.prime31.GameHelperUtils.getAppIdFromResource(GameHelperUtils.java:122)
> 06-15 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.prime31.GameHelperUtils.printMisconfiguredDebugInfo(GameHelperUtils.java:106)
> 06-15 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.prime31.GameHelper.giveUp(GameHelper.java:893) 06-15 15:53:20.615
> 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.prime31.GameHelper.onActivityResult(GameHelper.java:602) 06-15
> 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.prime31.PlayGameServicesPlugin.onActivityResult(PlayGameServicesPlugin.java:597)
> 06-15 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-15
> 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-15 15:53:20.615
> 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.prime31.ActivityProxyObjectHelper.onActivityResult(ActivityProxyObjectHelper.java:111)
> 06-15 15:53:20.615 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onActivityResult(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java:35)
> 06-15 15:53:20.623 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192) 06-15
> 15:53:20.623 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
> 06-15 15:53:20.623 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
> 06-15 15:53:20.623 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130) 06-15
> 15:53:20.623 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
> 06-15 15:53:20.623 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 06-15 15:53:20.623
> 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-15 15:53:20.631
> 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 06-15
> 15:53:20.631 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-15
> 15:53:20.631 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 06-15 15:53:20.631
> 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
> 06-15 15:53:20.631 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 06-15
> 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/? W/System.err:     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-15 15:53:20.638
> 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** App ID from          : ??? (failed to
> retrieve APP ID) 06-15 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: ****
> 06-15 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** Check that the
> above information matches your setup in  06-15 15:53:20.638
> 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** Developer Console. Also, check that
> you're logging in with the 06-15 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/?
> W/GameHelper: **** right account (it should be listed in the Testers
> section if 06-15 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: **** your
> project is not yet published). 06-15 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/?
> W/GameHelper: **** 06-15 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: ****
> For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide: 06-15
> 15:53:20.638 17069-17069/? W/GameHelper: ****
> http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

I've absoloutely made sure I'm using a test account, it's uploaded to google play and the APP Id is correct.

However the SHA1 fingerprint it gives me in the log is different to the one on googles servers even though it's the same APK I've installed on the device (E5:E0:84:E6:B7:74:78:4F:6C:DA:E7:C9:56:69:81:10:6C:12:04:E8 vs 45ad218212bb6ce583421e7506774612acb37909)

Any ideas how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a problem with **Drive API** being disabled. You have to enable it on the  [Google Play Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Comment: it was already on, i tried turning it off and on again to no avail. Out of curiosity is this a general API or do I need to find a way to turn it on for the specific app?

Comment: @soshiki **To interact with the Drive API, you need to enable the Drive API service for your app** https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk

Comment: Also make sure your App ID was incorrectly entered. Make sure that your game settings have  been published. What plugin are you using for the play-services? The official google plugin or one from prime32?

Comment: I ended up just making a new account but for what it's worth I think drive api being initially disabled was the cause of the issue, but since the app was in test for such a long time enabling drive api didn't seem to help.